Laravel 10 - CSRF token not working in others devices on my Laravel Server Rendering app
In order to test my app. I have made PHP accessible from the firewall, and it works. The app works very very well with any browser of my local machin.
Now the problem is that, I can not log-in with my android device web browser. The app appear very well on android but I can not log-in, I have always 419 | PAGE EXPIRED with an exception in the debug-bar: CRSF token mismatch.    Illimunate\Session\TokenMismatchException from the file vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 85
I have tried many ideas coming from this given solution but nothing works.
I have tried Laravel CSRF token not found
All those solutions are for apps using a front-end. My app is directly served from blade template in a very simple HTML/CSS setup.
I tried CSRF token not working in laravel by setting 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false), in config/session.php but nothing happened.

I've found a simple solution. But I can't just delete the main question because I suspect it might save someone one day, given that no one has really talked about it until now. read my answer bellow.

Laravel stores all its session information (user, token, flash, ...) in a single secured and encrypted cookie named appname_session (see cookie in config/session.php). That cookie is only available for the host registered as SESSION_DOMAIN. That is why you can not log-in using an other URL that differs with SESSION_DOMAIN.
When you are in development environment, YOU MUST comment that variable in your .env file in order to make your appname_session cookie available to others hostnames used by your application in development mode.
For those who want use Postman for the production environment and the same issue appears, here is a good tutorial i've found for front-end developers because it is not recommanded to delete SESSION_DOMAIN for production. Visit this link to see how they have done with it.
I hope this will save peoples losing their time like I did.
